# Why is this an endless loop? ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, activerecord, model

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :give_user_credit, :on => :update 

  def give_user_credit
    credit = User.current_user.credit + 3.8
    User.current_user.update_attribute(:credit, credit)
  end
end
```

When I use this the server hangs and when I come back to the application after a full reboot my credit is in the £1000's.

Whats going on here..

Thanks :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks to me like you are setting the `:give_user_credit callback` to run every time that the record is updated.

But since the callback updates the record, it then triggers the callback again, which will continue on and on...

Comment: Thanks for that ive moved the logic into the controller and now its working fine, shame the £3112.20 is fake :P

Comment: @Karl How about before_save :on => :update and then just don't call update_attribute...?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use this private method:

```
model.credit = 10
model.send(:update_without_callbacks)
```